# speech_recognition not recognition my words and not giving output

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    speak("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\\n")
    except Exception as e:
        speak("Say that again please...")
```

I have written this code which is not giving error but whenever i run the code its not recogniting my words and simplying returning speak("Say that again please...")

Comment: try printing the exception `e` and find out what is actually happening.